# How to put Preprocessor in C automatically

Tags: c

I am using Visual Studio Code v1.14.1.

In my program, I got a lot's of printf or some debug function.

I knew that I can put something like

```
#define DEBUG_PRINT  1

#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT
    printf(*****************);
#endif
```

But the problem is there got thousand of printf, I don't want manually add the preprocessor define. Do we got any method can automatically wrapped the target function around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want **every** call to `printf` to be covered by the debug flag, you can do this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT
#define printf(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define printf(...) 0
#endif
```

With this macro, if the flag is defined then the call to `printf` is unchanged.  If it is not, the call is replaced with the value 0.  The value is needed in case the return value of `printf` is used anyplace.

Comment: Is it workable for every function ? Example I got another function like print_log(), the same method will do ?

Comment: @JD_Newbie Yes it will work.  The only thing you would need to change is that the value in the non-debug case needs to match the return type of the function.  If the function's return type is `void`, make that case `(void)0`.